# "gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir" when signing git commit on Windows 10

Tags: git, github, cmd, gnupg

I'm creating gpg keys with Kleopatra (in order to sign my git commits) and while that works perfectly, when I try to list my keys with

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

I get the following errors:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir 
`C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\gnupg'
gpg: WARNING: using insecure memory!
```

I've already changed the permissions for `..\gnupg\` to only `"Daniel"` and removed the `SYSTEM and administrator permissions` in the properties window. What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) install Gpg4win

2) run `git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"`

Here is the full answer https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43809#issuecomment-366188770.
It helped me.

Comment: Extended answer.